# How to clone Bitbucket git into cPanel Git™ Version Control

Tags: git, bitbucket, cpanel

I have git into my Bitbucket account and I want clone those git into my cPanel Git™ Version Control. How to do that?

I was able pull git using cPanel terminal. but I want to make clone using cPanel Git™ Version Control.

We want to make bitbucket git clone using cPanel Git™ Version Control so that we can create more branches from cPanel git and do version control for cPanel copy. I tried to clone bitbucket git using **https, git and ssh url** into cPanel Git™ Version Control but then I am getting following error.

From **BitBucket**

```
git clone https://<AccountName>@bitbucket.org/<RepositoryName>/<BranchName>.git
```

Into **cPanel Git™ Version Control** But I am getting following error.

```
https://<AccountName>@bitbucket.org/<RepositoryName>/<BranchName>.git
```

[image]

Then i have tested with SSH and Git path from bitbucket

For SSH path I am getting following error.

```
ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<workspace_ID>/<repo_name>.git
```

[image]

Fog git url which is copied from **Clone button** in bitbucket, I am getting following error.

```
git@bitbucket.org:<workspace_ID>/<repo_name>.git
```

[image]

---

- I have created SSH Access keys into cPanel, Do i have to use that anywhere for cloning ??
- Can you guide me steps in details for cloning git from bitbucket into cPanel Git™ Version Control

Thank You.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, have you found a solution? The answer provided has the same result and I'm getting the same error messages as your screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to `repository settings` on Your Bitbucket Repository Console
2. Under `General` menu, click `Access keys`
3. Click `Add key` button
4. Open `id_rsa.pub` file from `cpanel file manager` that you have created
5. Copy and paste its contents to Bitbucket Access keys under `Key` form input, and click `Add SSH Key` button
6. On the CPanel Git™ Version Control, add and clone repository, if any error message, it will be create a `known_hosts` file in `cpanel file manager`.
7. Repeat step 6 one more time

Answer (score 0):

One of the issue can be that your keys are passphrase protected. The cPanle documentation link below has a note they passphrase protected keys are not supported:

**NOTE:** Keys that are passphrase protected are not compatible with cPanel Git™ Version Control.
If your existing keys require a passphrase, please make use of the section labeled: Option #1 - Generate a New Private and Public Key Pair to learn how to generate a compatible set of keys.

https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/4404218477207-How-to-Configure-SSH-Key-Authentication-for-Use-with-cPanel-Git-Version-Control

Interestingly enough, the built in SSH Key Generator does not allow to generate keys without passphrase, which makes it very confusing as the cPanel Git™ Version Control will not work with any generated keys via cPanel SSH Key Generator. The workaround is to generate passphrase less keys using terminal access.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go into your `cPanel` and then go into `Terminal`.
2. Use the terminal to generate an key by typing in: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C YourEmailAddress` leave the password as blank.
3. Go back to the main dashboard of your cPanel, then into `SSH Access` and then into `Manage SSH Keys`.
4. You will notice that the public key has been generated. Under `Public Keys` click on `View/Download` and copy the key.
5. Go into the bitbucket repo and click on `Repository settings` and then on `Access keys`.
6. Click on `Add Key` and add the public key from your Cpanel.

You should now be able to connect the repo, just keep in mind that under `Git™ Version Control` within the cPanel, the `Clone URL` should look like this `git@bitbucket.org:username/mysite.git` (replaced with your details).

You can get this in Bitbucket within the repo by clicking on `Commits` and then on `Clone`.