# cPanel Git Control can not manage to work although there is a .cpanel.yml

Tags: git, bitbucket, cpanel

I am new in Git. I use bitbucket. I was working localhost everything fine. Now, I want to upload the project to server. Thus, I would like to use Git Control that cPanel offers. my working root folder is

```
/home/user/public_html/orders
```

I have entered to this path via SSH and paste the clone link I took from Bitbucket. Everything fine. I saw the commits and so on.. Now I did some changes/adds/edits to localhost project, so I have more tha 10 new commits. If I try to "Update from remote" via cPanel, nothing change to my cpanel commits. There is a message that says:

"*A valid .cpanel.yml file exists. For more information, read our documentation.

No uncommitted changes exist on the checked-out branch*"

So I have created and uploaded many .cpanel.yml files, in order to make this work! For example:

```
---
deployment:
      tasks:
        - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/user/public_html/orders
        - /bin/cp -R * $DEPLOYPATH

---
deployment:
      tasks:
        - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/user/public_html
        - /bin/cp -r /home/user/orders/* $DEPLOYPATH
```

But still no luck..
I found many questions here, but couldn't find a solution
The .cpanel.yml file is inside my root path folder like I mention above:
/home/user/public_html/orders/.cpanel.yml

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I have found a solution on my own and made that worked.
In the last few days ago, bitbucket announce some changes, too! In order to connect your local project to bitbucket, you need to setup an "apps passwords", under "Personal Settings" option menu.
In this way, you do not need to enter your account's password every time you send a commit.

now, in order to connect cPanel "Git Version Control", you need to create a "SSH keys", under "Persoal Settings", too. Thus, cPanel gets authorization to connect with Bitbucket.
There is a nice tutorial too, in this link:
[How to clone Bitbucket git into cPanel Git™ Version Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62933298/how-to-clone-bitbucket-git-into-cpanel-git-version-control)